# How to make a Android TV app without using leanback lib

Tags: android, android-tv

Im new to Android TV development. I want to build an app without using `leanback` lib.But Android Studio automatically attaching `leanback` when selecting the platform as TV. How do i remove it?

PS-
My app is going to run inside a `webview` .

```
private AdvancedWebView mWebView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.setListener(this, this);
    mWebView.loadUrl("url for app hosted on server");
}
```

Is it a good decision for TV apps?

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need any of the android tv libraries or even to setup your project as an android tv project to get it on the android tv play store. I set my project up as a standard app (all those support libs make your apk large). Put a 320x180 icon in drawable. In the manifest just add

```
     <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" />
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
     android:banner="@drawable/banner"
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
```

If your using a webview and your ui is gonna be the same across all platforms you can use the leanback launcher intent in the same activity as your regular activity.

That's it.

Comment: thanks for the reply. If i'm using a webview how do i add video recommendations to the Home.

Answer (score 3):

Leanback is [required](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html#tv-activity) if you want to make Android TV App and upload it to the Play Store.

> An application intended to run on TV devices must declare a launcher
>   activity for TV in its manifest using a CATEGORY_LEANBACK_LAUNCHER
>   intent filter. This filter identifies your app as being enabled for
>   TV, and is required for your app to be considered a TV app in Google
>   Play

What you can do is set leanback required to false

> If you are developing an app that runs on mobile (phones, wearables,
>   tablets, etc.) as well as Android TV, set the required attribute value
>   to false. If you set the required attribute value to true, your app
>   will run only on devices that use the Leanback UI.

```
<manifest>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="false" />
    ...
</manifest>
```